# Custom callout View with xip

Tags: xcode, xib, callouts

I'm trying to set a custom callout view with a xib I created however it doesn't show up.
When I tap in a pin the app is crashing and show the follow error

[image]

It's anyone that can help me?
You can find the code here.
https://github.com/andreasvas/xcode

Comment: What/where is that view that is getting the crash when tapped?

Comment: in map when I tapped at the annotation xib doesn't show and then is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interface builder for your `CalloutView.xib`;

- Make sure `File's Owner` is blank (NSObject). And don't forget to remove outlet references.
- `CalloutViewController` is a `UIView` subclass, So set it for the top most UIView, not the `File's Owner'. And don't forget to re-hook your outlets.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's works. But now I have another issue. While I tap to another pin the previous View doesn't close.

Comment: Hold a reference for it and just remove it as a subview. If you can't make it work, feel free to open up an another question so we can help.

Comment: I make a new question